# Why do I get an error of "index out of bounds" in Swift when appending a new file?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm very new with swift and I have a function on my app which sets a schedule for an audio recording to happen automatically. The recording successfully starts and stops at the given times. However, I get a runtime error when I hit the button “recordings” to check for the created recording file.

Would you happen to know why that’s the case?

I didn't think it should be a problem as I'm only automating a pre-existing function. I initially have a function which sucessfully records when start and stop button for the function is manually pressed and the file is created within the folder "recordings"

Here’s my code:

```
/*
 This will change recordings to fileitmes and add to an array, this array is used by the table view, which will then show the recordings
 */
func addToRecordings(folder: String) {
    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let path = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(folder).absoluteURL
    do {
        let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: path, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
        //only want the wav files
        let wavFiles = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "wav" }
        for file in wavFiles{
            let fileName = file.lastPathComponent
            let start = fileName.index(fileName.startIndex, offsetBy: 26)
            let end = fileName.index(fileName.endIndex, offsetBy: -4)
            let range = start..<end
            //create id to help sort the wav files 
            let id = Int(fileName[range]) ?? 0
            if let fileAttributes = try? FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: file.path) {
                if let bytes = fileAttributes[.size] as? Int64 {
                    let fileSize = fileByteCountFormatter.string(fromByteCount: bytes)
                    let recording = FileItem(id: id, fileName: fileName, fileSizeSpecific: fileSize, fileSizeBytes: bytes, fileLocation: folder+fileName)
                    self.recordings.append(recording!)
                }
            }
        }
        self.recordings = self.recordings.sorted(by: {$0.id < $1.id})
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    if recordings.isEmpty{
        recordingsActionButton.isHidden = true
        self.selectAllButton.isHidden = true
        progressBar.isHidden = true
    }else {
        recordingsActionButton.isHidden = false
        self.selectAllButton.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

The error is here:
`let start = fileName.index(fileName.startIndex, offsetBy: 26)`

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Please do not post images of code, can you update your question to include the code? Images of code make it hard for those who are trying to help you as they are unable to easily copy the code from an image. By including the code in your question you make your question self contained and more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Not related to your question but using sorted to mutate your collection is pointless. There isn’t sort mutating method exactly for this purpose

Comment: *there is a sort

Comment: Add a `print(fileName)` right before where you get the error, does it print what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

This line will give index out of bounds if `fileName` is shorter than 26 characters:

```
let start = fileName.index(fileName.startIndex, offsetBy: 26)
```

Comment: Hi there, I think it was wrong to assume that this is a valid index for every fileName created. But now I'm not quite sure how to go about with it now.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the lines from "let start = ..." to "let id = ..."?
I mean, what is "id" meant to end up being?

Comment: Don’t post comments as answers please

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - I have edited my answer so it doesn’t contain any comments. It now answers the question and does nothing else.